# How can i seperate joomla sub menus in different modules

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I have 3 level menus and i need to display each sub menu in diferrent modules. ie,

This is a 3 level menu, i need to display main menu in MODULE_ONE, and second level in MODULE_TWO and third level in  MODULE_THREE position correspondingly, with out the tree structure . The modules three modules are in different position. How can i implement this in joomla 2.5. I have check and been able to display on second level but not possible to display 3rd level. please reply if there is a

thank you.[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Splitmenu configuration of RocketTheme's [RokNavMenu](http://www.rockettheme.com/extensions-downloads/free/1048-roknavmenu)

[Here's a discussion](http://www.rockettheme.com/forum/index.php?f=208&t=152890&p=754210&hilit=3%20level%20splitmenu&rb_v=viewtopic#p754210) on how to accomplish that.

Comment: hi I still have trouble in displaying the third level module , please check the attachment

Comment: How do you have the level limits set for the 3rd level module?

Comment: For the first level i set the limits to 0 to 1, and for the second 1 to 2 and for the third 2 to all, but the second leve is displaying in side the third, please check the image i have attached

Comment: Looks to me like the second menu should only show 2 (2-2), since 1 is already shown in the first menu. No?

Comment: I have given the first menu 0-0 and second to 1-1 , and third to 2-2 , but the third not displaying, in order to display the third level we should have to give 1- all , with show  Sub-menu Items on, which would display like the above.

Comment: At this point it may be simpler to hide the 2.1 items with CSS. I'll try to help if you can share a demo.

Comment: It is simple you can try creating a demo menu as show in above picture.. I think ists problem with joomla, the third level not working

Answer (score 1):

You can display 3 levels in 3 modules from the same menu, of course the second level's content will be determined by the first level selection; this will apply also to the third level.

However, please note that mod_menu used to have inadequate cache support, so by all means DO DISABLE the cache on the modules, else they won't work or will work funny (not showing the current page highlighted... changing the second menu "20" when you click on the first menu "3" ...)

Comment: That's good to know. Thanks. I've been using RT stuff for so long I've lost track of what Joomla core can do on its own.